# Arch/GNS3: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 3080: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux

I installed GNS3 install on Arch following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNS3) and [this](https://medium.com/@Ninja/install-gns3-on-arch-manjaro-linux-the-right-way-c5a3c4fa337d). I restarted the machine already but it keeps me telling it could not connect to localhost on port 3080. By default, when GNS3 is not running the port is not open:

```
$ ss -tlp | grep 3080
$
```

The last line below indicates something, no?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'WordCompleter' from 'prompt_toolkit.contrib.completers' (/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/contrib/completers/__init__.py)
```

A screenshot with the GUI error and GNS3 Doctor (Help -> GNS3 Doctor) are below.

When I run it, (either as normal user or root), it says:

```
$ gns3
2019-08-11 19:37:33 INFO root:126 Log level: INFO
2019-08-11 19:37:33 INFO main:259 GNS3 GUI version 2.1.21
2019-08-11 19:37:33 INFO main:260 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 GNS3 Technologies Inc.
2019-08-11 19:37:33 INFO main:262 Application started with /usr/bin/gns3
2019-08-11 19:37:38 ERROR local_server:489 Local server process has stopped
2019-08-11 19:37:38 ERROR local_server:491 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gns3server", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/main.py", line 82, in main
    from gns3server.run import run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/run.py", line 32, in <module>
    from gns3server.web.web_server import WebServer
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/web/web_server.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .route import Route
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/web/route.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..compute.error import NodeError, ImageMissingError
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/compute/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .dynamips import Dynamips
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/compute/dynamips/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .dynamips_factory import DynamipsFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/compute/dynamips/dynamips_factory.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .nodes.ethernet_switch import EthernetSwitch
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/compute/dynamips/nodes/ethernet_switch.py", line 25, in <module>
    from gns3server.utils.asyncio.embed_shell import EmbedShell, create_telnet_shell
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gns3server/utils/asyncio/embed_shell.py", line 26, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.contrib.completers import WordCompleter
ImportError: cannot import name 'WordCompleter' from 'prompt_toolkit.contrib.completers' (/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/contrib/completers/__init__.py)

2019-08-11 19:38:03 CRITICAL utils.progress_dialog:181 WaitForConnectionWorker thread stopping with an error: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 3080: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2019-08-11 19:38:03 CRITICAL progress_dialog.py:183 Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 3080: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are `this and this` ?

Comment: I totally forgot to add the link. So, [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNS3) and [this](https://medium.com/@Ninja/install-gns3-on-arch-manjaro-linux-the-right-way-c5a3c4fa337d)